# Laravel 5 set global variable for config file (mailchimp)

Tags: laravel, mailchimp, laravel-5

I use `mailchimp` inside **Laravel 5.2** for newsletter. 
I want the `api key` and `list ID` to be set from admin panel, saved in database, and then use dynamic in config file for mailchimp. My problem is I cant query the database inside config. Is there a way to share the variable like in `view()->shar`e and then be available even in config files?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've made the `api key` and `list ID` changeable by user, I think they no longer have anything to do with config or env. I suggest to take them out from config. And then you can get their values with Eloquent:

```
// Assume your table name is 'settings', with 'code' and 'value' fields
$apiKey = Setting::where('code', 'mailchimp_api_key')->value('value');
$listId = Setting::where('code', 'mailchimp_list_id')->value('value');
```

Comment: Ok, but config/laravel-newsletter ask me for this values in order to be set correctly. So where should i put your code in order to be used? I use spatie/laravel-newsletter.

Comment: What about the code posted earlier? Seems to work. The one with Config::set().

Comment: Try `Config::set('laravel-newsletter.mailChimp.apiKey', $apiKey);`

Answer (score 0):

And what if i use this:

```
Config::set('laravel-newsletter.mailChimp.apiKey', $data['mailchimp']['apiKey']);
Config::set('laravel-newsletter.mailChimp.lists.subscribers.id', $data['mailchimp']['listID'])
```